# PHP mailer Error receiving an email

Tags: php

I am using the code below for the mailing list of the website I am working on, and it's working fine on my localhost using my credentials and on some other server using some other credentials were given to me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();                       
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mailing_list";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)    
    or die('Error querying the database!');

    $mail->IsSMTP();  
    $mail->Host= "smtp"; 
    $mail->Username= "some email address was given to me"; 
    $mail->Password= "password"; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->From ="some email address was given to me";
    $mail->FromName ="CSCA";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $to = $row['email'];
    $mail->ClearAddresses();        
    $mail->AddAddress($to);         
            $mail->Subject= $_POST['subject'];

        $mail->Body = "Dear $first_name $last_name,\n" . $_POST['body'];
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;

        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
            echo 'Message was not sent.';
            echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

Now when I use the following code for the contact us page of the same website it works fine one my localhost using my own credentials, but it doesn't work on the other server I used above. I got a message in the spam 'mail delivery failed'. I don't know how with the same credentials you can send mail but you can't receive! I mean with the same server and same credentials you the mailing list works fine but the contact us form gives an error. Is there a way to fix that??

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();     

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

    $mail->IsSMTP();  
    $mail->Host="smtp"; 
    $mail->Username="some email address was given to me"; 
    $mail->Password="password"; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
    $mail->From =$email;
    $mail->FromName =$name; 
    $mail->AddAddress("some email address was given to me", "Some name");

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";


    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
      echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      exit;
    }
```

Comment: what is the error it gives?

Comment: ^Same what @JanakaRRajapaksha said + This error is most probably happening because the server that you were trying to send the mail to doesn't except mails from your ip address. Services like GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail etc. don't except email if it doesn't come from a trusted ip for security. If it wasn't so, imagine, anyone across the world can forge email addresses easily!

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha  like when I use the contact us page, instead of finding what i sent in my sent emails i find an email in the spam saying Mail delivery failed to the following recipients. So how can i create a contact us page without facing such this error??

Comment: @Mima Mail delivery failed with what message exactly? It must give some reason as to why the delivery failed...

Comment: @AwalGarg  

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  x@gmail.com
    (ultimately generated from y@z.acm.org)
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [ip add]:
    ip add Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's

Comment: @Mima As I suspected. You have to contact your service provider and tell him that you are unable to send emails from the IP you are provided with. They and only they can resolve this problem... I might be wrong, so I am not posting an answer to this. But I highly recommend, you try to contact your ISP or domain provider...

Comment: @AwalGarg  Ok will do that thank you!